# Conditions to trade ETFs with Schwab or other

Tags: trading, etf

I am looking for the conditions to start trading ETFs such as SPX and TQQQ. While trying to do it with an interactive brokers account, it tells me that I have 2 options,

1. Be an institutional investor (Which I am not)
2. Have at least 200k$ so they let me invest in ETFs (Which also restricts me)

What options are valid to try to open an investment account where I can trade ETFs without needing to comply with those conditions.

Investor Profile: European investor, with no social security number in the US, planning to invest around 5000$

Comment: I suspect it's not a bar on trading ETFs, but a bar on trading _leveraged_ ETFs.

Comment: Why are you not using a European broker as you seem to be not from the US? Some US ETFs may be slightly cheaper but in terms of taxation you are opening pandora's box by using a US broker